# ObservableCollection find items in SubSub ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, observablecollection

i have some Classes combined in ObservableCollection(s) and bind to a wpf Treeview Itemsource

Simple Example ([...] = other var's):

```
Class A
{
object id
[...]
ObservableCollection<B>
}

Class B
{
object id
[...]
ObservableCollection<C>
}

Class C
{
object id
[...]
ObservableCollection<D>
}

Class D
{
object id
[...]

}
```

Now the User press a Button inside the Tree to add a new Item, i know from the Button if the Class is a, b, c or d and the TAG Attrib from the Button give me the "id" (the ID is only inside a Class(!) Collection unique, this means: in and over all ObservableCollection B.id is unique, but A.id and B.id or a C.id can have the same id)

to add a new item to ObservableCollection B is easy

```
(((ObservableCollection<A>)treeView.ItemsSource).Where(A => A.id.ToString() == ((Button)sender).Tag.ToString())).First().B.Add(B_new);
```

but how can i get the one from the C,D, and E Sub-Sub-Collections?
Where(A => A.B.id ... is not working

Comment: "_but how can i get the one from the C,D, and E_" by simply stringing along `.First` or `.FirstOrDefault` clauses like `Acollection.First(a => {selector for a particular A}).B.First(b => {selector for a particular B}).C.First( c => {selector for a particular C}).D.First(d => ....` and so on. Note that in a selector for A, it would be rather difficult trying to select a particular B like you tried to do with `Where(A => A.B.id`. It would very likely be possible, but such code would hardly classify as "readable"...

Comment: thanks, but my Problem is, i dont know the IDs from the  A, B, ... i only know " in a Class C Collection is a item with ID=1235, i dont know anything about the B or A Class "above", i think i must do it like the "old" way .. looping trough the full itemsource